# CAN strongly typed DataSet work with SQL Server 2000

Tags: c#, asp.net, sql-server-2005, sql-server-2000, strongly-typed-dataset

I've written a Strongly Typed DataSet dll with SQL Server 2005. And I've been used name parameters in DataSet Queries.

Can I only set the connectionstring point to a SQL Server 2000 for this dll without any modifies.

Info:
WebSite : Asp.net (C# 3.5 LinQ To DataSet )
DataSet : Strongly Typed DataSet( develop with SQL Server 2005 and named parameters)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think yes, here is a proof:

http://weblogs.asp.net/scottgu/archive/2006/01/15/Building-a-DAL-using-Strongly-Typed-TableAdapters-and-DataTables-in-VS-2005-and-ASP.NET-2.0.aspx